# Using Custom views in SP2013 document sets

Tags: custom-view, sharepoint-2013, document-set

In sp2010 with a document set content type in a library  i can have a default view on the library, showing my document set content types and on the welcome page of the content type i can define a different view showing the detail of the documents in the set...

In sp2013 I cannot see a mechanism of doing this. The document set welcome page holds a document set contents web part that will not allow me to set the view, it picks up the default view of the library... Has  anyone figured out how to do this?

I don't have access (or skills) to visual studio, but am quite familiar with sp-designer and infopath, though i am hoping that it can be achieved through the SP UI

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create your view in the Document Library, then in your library settings, click on your Document Set content type and then select Document Set Settings.

On this page you should see a "Welcome Page View". You can select your view from the drop down box.